# React this.state not updating correctly when called within if else statement with use of immutability-helper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a simple horizontal tab bar component. If a user clicks on a tab, some logic is carried out by the container.

The tab states are tracked in the container through *this.state*. One of the props of the container is an array called 'options'. The length dictates the amount of tabs in the tab bar.

```
constructor(props){
        super(props)

        var arrayWithTabs = []
        var isSelected;

        this.props.options.map((option, i) => {

            if (option == this.props.selected){
                isSelected = true
            } else {
                isSelected = false 
            }
            var tabObject = {
                optionName: option,
                isSelected: isSelected
            }
            arrayWithTabs.push(tabObject)

        })

        this.state = {
            options: arrayWithTabs,
        }
```

Whenever a user clicks the handleClick is fired:

```
     updateState = (index,isSelected) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return update(prevState.options,{
                [index]: {
                    isSelected:{$set: isSelected}
                }
            })
        })
    }

    handleClick(e) {
        this.state.options.map((option, i) => {

            const isSelected = option.optionName == e.target.id;

            this.updateState(i, isSelected);
        })     
      }


    componentDidUpdate(){
        console.log(this.state.options)
    }
```

In order to handle the async behaviour of setState I read you should never directly read from this.state but to create a function within setState which takes in prevState.

However, when clicking on any tab, componetDidUpdate() returns the following:

[{optionName: "Tab1", isSelected: false}
{optionName: "Tab2", isSelected: false}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the map function returns an array. You should use forEach if you do not want to return anything from inside.

Secondly in constructor you should avoid using this.props because you are already getting props. Use that one.

At last you can do the following in handleClick method

```
handleClick(e) {
    const options = this.state.options.map((option, i) => {

        var isSelected = option.optionName === e.target.id;
        return {optionName: option.optionName, isSelected: isSelected}
    });
    this.setState({options})
  }
```

Also you can modify the constructor as follows

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)

    var options = props.options.map((option) => {

        var isSelected = (option == this.props.selected)
        return {
            optionName: option,
            isSelected: isSelected
        }

    })

    this.state = {
        options: options
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Parth Pandya. I used your code and it works as expected now! I am however not exactly sure why my own handleClick together with updateState does not work. It would be great if you could point out the exact mistakes / corrections I should make there in order for it to work with the immutability-helper update function. So I can use it somewhere next time.

Comment: The problem is that the updateState is called for every option in array of options. In updateState the setState method is taking previous state and changing only the value for the given index. Now suppose for true it has actually changed the state which you require. But this.setState is an asynchronous function which means it is not guaranteed that in the next iteration it will get the updated state. So the option for which the isSelected is false in handleClick, the updateState will probably take the state with initialized values in constructor and will just set false to the given index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback to ensure the `setState` has finished, for example:

```
addNewTabs(newOptions) {
    this.setState({ options:newOptions }, () => {
         console.log("Finished updating state:", this.state);
         // Do something with the updated state here...
    });
}
```

Try restructuring your code to something like this perhaps:

```
handleClick(e) {

  var updatedState;

  this.state.options.map((option, i) => {
    const isSelected = option.optionName == e.target.id;
    updatedState = update(this.state.options, {
      [i]: {$set:{optionName: option.optionName, isSelected:isSelected}}
    });  
  });

  this.setState({ options:updatedState }, () => {
    console.log(updatedState);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the restructure suggestion. I read up on this.setState a little more and apparently you can't directly read from this.state when updating state. Instead you should use a function within this.setState with using prevState. Still not successful however. I've updated the post..